# ts(2322): 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>' is not assignable to type '(value: OptionValue) => void'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I am learning Typescript generic integrate with React, read [this article](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/passing-generics-to-jsx-elements-in-typescript) and follow the article's code, But got this error:

```
Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>' is not assignable to type '(value: OptionValue) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'OptionValue' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<string>'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<string>'.ts(2322)
Select.tsx(15, 3): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ISelectProps<OptionValue>'
```

Here is my whole code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Select from './Select'

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const targets = [
    { value: 'es3', label: 'ECMAScript 3' },
    { value: 'es5', label: 'ECMAScript 5' },
    { value: 'es2015', label: 'ECMAScript 2015' },
    { value: 'es2016', label: 'ECMAScript 2016' },
    { value: 'es2017', label: 'ECMAScript 2017' },
    { value: 'es2018', label: 'ECMAScript 2018' },
    { value: 'es2019', label: 'ECMAScript 2019' },
    { value: 2019, label: 'ECMAScript 2019' },
  ]

  const [target, setTarget] = useState('es2019')

  return (
    <>
      {/* <Select value={target} onChange={(value) => setTarget(value)} /> */}
      <Select options={targets} value={target} onChange={setTarget} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Using generic in this `Select` Component

```js
/* eslint-disable react/destructuring-assignment */
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'

export type OptionValue = string | number
export type Option<T extends OptionValue> = {
  value: T
  label: string
}

interface ISelectProps<T extends OptionValue> {
  options: Option<T>[]
  value: T
  onChange: (value: T) => void
}

const Select = <T extends OptionValue>(props: ISelectProps<T>) => {
  const { options, onChange } = props
  const handleOnChange = useCallback((e: React.FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const { selectedIndex } = e.currentTarget
    const selectedOption = options[selectedIndex]
    onChange(selectedOption.value)
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])

  return (
    // eslint-disable-next-line unicorn/consistent-destructuring
    <select value={props.value} onChange={handleOnChange}>
      {options.map((option) => (
        <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
          {option.label}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  )
}

export default React.memo(Select)
```

codesandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-typescript-demo-forked-2d4ys?file=/src/index.tsx)

I know that I can explicitly pass the `OptionValue` type to `useState` to solve this problem like this:

```js
const [target, setTarget] = useState<OptionValue>('es2019')
```

But I found that this [article](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/passing-generics-to-jsx-elements-in-typescript) did not do this, and this manner is not typescript generic, right?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your referenced article all the `values` of `targets` were either `string` or `number`. In your code the `values` of `targets` contain both.

when you call

```
useState('es2019')
```

I think Typescript infers that the `target` is of type `string` (It can't infer that this could also be a `number`).

So with

```
const [target, setTarget] = useState<OptionValue>('es2019')
```

you're basically telling typescript: I want to initialize this with a `string` but it could also be a number.

A weird work around would also be:

```
const [target, setTarget] = useState(targets[6].value);
```

Comment: `const [target, setTarget] = useState(targets[6].value);` This seems doesn't work

Comment: @Liam_1998 Use `const [target, setTarget] = useState<string | number>("es2019");` as (also) suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This article did not this because `value` in `targets` always have type is `string` OR `number`. So he can declare state `target` without `OptionValue`, just need `target` has type as the same with type of `value`.

In your case, the `value` in `targets` has both type `string` AND `number`. So when you declare state `target`, you need to add type `OptionValue`

Comment: But I tried to delete the last item of  `target`, `{ value: 2019, label: 'ECMAScript 2019' }`, it still reminded me the same error. :-(